# JQuery string 'randomizer' clustering characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a password generator based on the options provided by the user. My current script allows users to select uppercase, lowercase, numeric and special characters. This works perfectly and strings are generated to to the user's required length however upon generation, numbers cluster at the string with letters clustering at the beginning. A single special character parts the two. Do you have any suggestions on how to improve the process?

```
$('document').ready(function() {
$('button').click(function() {
    var lower = "";
    var upper = "";
    var numeric = "";
    var special = "";
    var string_length = "";


    if($('#12').is(':checked')) { string_length = 12; };
    if($('#16').is(':checked')) { string_length = 16; };
    if($('#18').is(':checked')) { string_length = 18; };
    if($('#22').is(':checked')) { string_length = 22; };
    if($('#24').is(':checked')) { string_length = 24; };
    if($('#custom').is(':checked')) { $('#custom').show(); $('#custom').val(); } else { $('#custom').hide(); };

    if($('#ch1').is(':checked')) { lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; } else { lower = ""; };
    if($('#ch2').is(':checked')) { upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; } else { upper = ""; };
    if($('#ch3').is(':checked')) { numeric = "0123456789"; } else { numeric = ""; };
    if($('#ch4').is(':checked')) { special = "!£$%^&*()_-+={};:@~#?/"; } else { special = ""; };

    var chars = lower + upper + numeric + special;

    var randomstring = '';
    var charCount = 0;
    var numCount = 0;

    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        if((Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0) && numCount < 3 || charCount >= 5) {
            var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            randomstring += rnum;
            numCount += 1;
        } else {
            var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
            randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
            charCount += 1;
        }
    }
    $('span.string').html(randomstring);
});
});
```

The options 16 length, lowercase, uppercase, numeric and special characters returns something like **e046pzw%65760294**.

Comment: It should be noted that IDs starting with numbers are NOT valid until HTML5, and therefore may not work in older browsers.

Comment: @Kolink Much appreciated, will take a look at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is your culprit:

```
if((Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0) && numCount < 3 || charCount >= 5) {
```

It says:

- The first 3 characters have a bit over 50/50 chance of being numbers. The "then" is always a number and the "else" is a number sometimes depending on options.
- After you have 5 "else" selected chars (which means after col 8), you will always have a number.

This is because the "&&" takes precedence over the "||". I suggest using some parentheses to surround the OR clause if you want to have a 50/50 plus chance of using the digit. I also included an alternate way to do 50/50.

```
if ((Math.random() < 0.5) && (numCount < 3 || charCount >= 5)) {
```

I'm not sure why you want numbers to have precedence.

Comment: I should point out that this doesn't explain why, as you suggest, there will always be one special char in the middle. Is it always the same column and never anywhere else?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution. Just my five cents:

```
$(function(){

    $('input, select').change(function(){

        var s = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(i, v){
                return v.value;
            }).get().join(''),
            result = '';

        for(var i=0; i < $('#length').val(); i++)
            result += s.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * s.length));

        $('#result').val(result);        
    });

});
```

Just to give you some ideas. I'm fully aware of that this doesn't take any "type count" in to consideration.

http://jsfiddle.net/m5y3e/

Comment: You might want to show how you store the "value"s for the checkboxes. Its pretty slick. I still don't know why OP wanted the complex part with the first 3 chars and any chars over 8 to prefer digits even if digits isn't checked. Yours is more even-minded.

Comment: @LeeMeador Thanks. I just wanted to show OP how you could make something similar and still keep it generic. All those `if`s hurts my eyes ;) I think he'll be able to figure out the checkbox part at the fiddle.